# node.js stalls after connecting to local mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect to my database on mongodb and fetch some data from it. But right after establishing a connection the terminal stalls and I have to ctrl+C.

This is my code

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const dbName = 'inventory';
const dbUrl = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${dbName}`;

// Define the schema and model for the "cars" collection
const carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  make: String,
  model: String,
  year: Number
});

const Car = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);

// Connect to the MongoDB server
mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Connected to database '${dbName}'`);

    // Define a GET route handler that fetches all cars from the database

    app.get('/cars', async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const cars = await Car.find();
        console.log(cars); // Log the fetched cars to the console
        res.json(cars);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
      }
    });

    // Start the Express app
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

I know I have established a connection because I get this in my console

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-13T21:12:56.152-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn29","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53075","client":"conn29","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|Mongoose","version":"5.3.0|7.1.1"},"platform":"Node.js v16.17.1, LE","os":{"name":"win32","architecture":"x64","version":"10.0.19045","type":"Windows_NT"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-13T21:13:06.654-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53096","uuid":"9611eab4-7a75-49a0-9b44-d644599fe37c","connectionId":30,"connectionCount":18}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-13T21:13:06.656-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn30","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53096","client":"conn30","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|Mongoose","version":"5.3.0|7.1.1"},"platform":"Node.js v16.17.1, LE","os":{"name":"win32","architecture":"x64","version":"10.0.19045","type":"Windows_NT"}}}}
```

I also get in my console log

```
Connected to database 'inventory'
Server is listening on port 3000
```

I feel like the problem is with my machine because I don't know what else to try.
I was previously having an issue where my python app could connect to my mongodb but my node.js app couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to manually insert a document into the database, and then see if your setup can read it. Also, make sure the server is running correctly and that nothing else is running on port 3000, your firewall is configured correctly, etc.

Are you trying to use MongoDB cross-platform? For example, a linux terminal connecting to a windows hosted mongodb? If so, that will not work, at least not easily.
I had a situation where everything appeared to be working (windows mongodb compass and WSL terminal), but no documents were actually being inserted. The connection looked like it was there, but it was not. I fixed it by using windows powershell instead of WSL. When both the mongodb connection and the terminal were on Windows, it worked.

Comment: The server is up and running fine because I am able to read and write to it with python. I also tried turning off my firewall, and no luck. 

I just checked connections I have listening on port 3000, it was empty but when I ran my node.js code, I got two connections (looks like ipv4 and ipv6) TCP, listening on 15236.